# Set Object Property from other Object Property Question

Tags: c#, clone, parameter-passing

I'm very sorry if the Topic name doesnt match my problem. I was up to google it up, but I havn't any idea how my "problem" is called :(

I think thats a really basic question, but I think it's important to understand.
First of all I'll show the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            A a = new A();
            a.x = 5;
            a.y = 41;

            B b = new B();
            b.a = 14;
            b.b = a.y;
            b.c = a;

            a.x += 10;
            a.y -= 30;
        }
    }

    class A
    {
        public int x;
        public int y;
    }

    class B
    {
        public int a;
        public int b;
        public A c;
    }
}
```

I've got some very basic classes A and B. B can hold an instance of A. The "problem" I have, is:
If a pass A to B and set a property of A (`a.y -= 30;`) the value of `b.b` also changes. How do I avoid that?
I just want `b.b` to be the value of `a.y`. But if `a.y` changes, `b.b` should not!
Is the only way to do that, creating a Clone of the objects and then pass it?

Comment: Do you actually mean that you want **b.c** (not b.b) to remain the same when the value of a.y changes?

Comment: Didn't you mean that after passing a to b: `b.c = a;` then doing `a.y -= 30` the value of `b.c.y` also changes?

Comment: changing value of `b.c.y` also changes the value of `a.y`. 

i guess that's what u meant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything works as expected

[image]

Answer (score 1):

with

b.c = a;

you are passing a reference to an object.

to avoid this, you have to use a copy of the object. a clone, as you already recognized.

Comment: @steyca: nothing is wrong. but you should KNOW what you are doing. with b.c = a you are copying a pointer, not the object.

Answer (score 0):

With `a.y -= 30`, `b.b` will not change.  An `int` is a value-type, not a reference type.

(Your assumption is incorrect)